# How to add class to an element in Html or via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a class to an element via javascript and it does not work. If I trying to add via html it still does not work. It's the active class.

```js
var sliderIndex = 0;

let next2 = document.querySelector(".next2");
let prev2 = document.querySelector(".prev2");

function showNews(n) {
  debugger;
  const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('news');
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    sliderIndex = slider.length - 1;
  }
  if (n > slider.length - 1) {
    sliderIndex = 0
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", " ");
  }
  slider[sliderIndex].style.display = 'block';
  dots[sliderIndex].classList.add('active')
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showNews(sliderIndex = n)
}

function incrementSlides2(n) {
  showNews((sliderIndex += n))
}

next2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  incrementSlides2(1);
});
prev2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  incrementSlides2(-1);
});

showNews(sliderIndex)
```

```css
#section-three .slideshow-container2 {
  position: relative;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .prev2,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2 {
  top: 50%;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .prev2:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .company-btn,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn {
  margin: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .company-btn:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content p,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 2rem 8rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content h1,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content {
  background: white;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (1fr)[3];
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem 6rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .media-room {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .img {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .texter {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more {
  color: green;
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  grid-row: 4;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots .dot:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots .dot .active {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-three">
    <div class="container slideshow-container2">
      <div class="news">
        <div class="news-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1>OUR PEOPLE ARE OUT STONGEST ASSET </h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptate fugiat, molestias adipisci
            voluptas
            nisi blanditiis a aliquid accusantium omnis, soluta animi praesentium ipsam fugit? Non ea nisi optio
            dolores.voluptate fugiat, molestias adipisci voluptas
            nisi blanditiis a aliquid accusantium omnis, soluta animi praesentium ipsam fugit? Non ea nisi optio
            dolores.
          </p>
          <a class="my-2 wiew-more" href="#">WIEW MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news news2">
        <div class="news2-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1 class="media-room">MEDIA ROOM </h1>
          <div class="img">
            <img src="/Core/img/media.jpg" style="width:500px" alt="">
          </div>
          <p class="texter">London, June 2019 – If you want to enjoy wireless technology while gaming an unnoticeable
            latency is key.
            Sennheiser introduces the GSP 670, Sennheiser's first wireless gaming headset. The GSP 670 gives gamers
            significantly more freedom of movement than wired models. The audio specialist has integrated a proprietary
            low-latency connection that guarantees a reliable and stable transmission with near-zero delay. In addition,
            the GSP 670 offers Sennheiser’s renowned wearing comfort and premium audio performance.

          </p>
          <a class="my-2 wiew-more" href="#">WIEW MORE2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="dots">
        <span class="dot width" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prev2">Prev</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next2">Next</a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the *minimal*)

Comment: `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` - why are you linking *there*?! Or to `<a class="my-2 wiew-more" href="#">` for that matter? (Use a button)

Comment: "*need to add some text here because i can't post the question without an amount of words*" instead of padding the question with more words, can you specify *which* class you're trying to add, how, what is failing and, in general, walk us through your problem.

Comment: Your CSS selector for "active" should end with `.dot.active` not `.dot .active`.

Comment: Also when removing "active" you should do it through the `.classList` API instead of using `.replace()`. You already use `.classList` to add the class.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
> dots[sliderIndex].classList.add('active')
> ```

You are adding the class to one of the elements which already has the class `dot`

> ```
> #section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots .dot .active
> ```

But you have a **descendant combinator** between the `.dot` class selector and the `.active` class selector. The element with `active` isn't a descendant of the element with `dot`, it is the **same** element. Remove the combinator.

Comment: i.e. make it `#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots .dot.active` instead